# How do I unit test functional code? (not OOP)

Tags: php, functional-programming, phpunit

I'm working in a hybrid environment. Some sections are procedurally written, some are object oriented, some follow the functional paradigm.

As we refactor code, we're implementing unit tests to all of our code as we come across it, and I'm currently in a functional area of code. However, all instruction I've ever seen for phpunit is about testing methods inside of objects and classes.

I've *heard* it's easier to do unit testing on functional code, but have never seen an example. How do you test functional code using phpunit?

For example, if I have a function

```
function foo($bar, $baz){
 if (!isset($bar["foo"]){
   return false;
 }
 return foobar($bar["foo"], $baz);
}
```

And I currently have a test.php that looks like this:

```
<?php 
declare(strict_types=1);
require("../backend/foo.php");
use PHPUnit\Framework\Testcase;
final class functionTest extends TestCase{
   public function testTheFooFunction(): void{
      // ???? 
   }
}
```

What would a unit test for this function, using phpunit, look like? Am I even on the right track with my test.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just test the same way as any other units. Nothing special here

```php
function foobar($foo, $baz) {
    return $foo + $baz;
}

function foo($bar, $baz){
    if (!isset($bar["foo"]) {
        return false;
    }
    return foobar($bar["foo"], $baz);
}

public function testTheFooFunction(): void{
    $bar = ['foo' => 1];
    $baz = 2;
    
    $result = foo($bar, $baz);
    
    self::assertEquals(3, $result);
}
```